# Javascript: .then() in promise is not executing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, promise

I want a script file just for accessing a JSON from a url. I want to have a method to return the JSON object from the script into a var in a separate script file then modify it accordingly. Obviously since javascript is asynchronous it fails if I simply write it out. Therefore I must use a promise:

```
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  access(userSearchText); //send user input to get appropriate JSON object
});

promise1.then(function(value) {
  var getData = returnData();     //method that returns JSON object from the other script
  alert(getData);                 //print out the returned JSON object
  console.log("we have finished");
});
```

But this is not printing out anything. The alert does not occur at all and nothing is being printed in the console. I am using jquery to access the url in the other script and I have a .done after accessing it in the script for retrieving the JSON as: access.js

```
var sendData;

(function() {

        jqxhr = $.getJSON( url, {

        })
        .done(function( data ) {
            sendData = data;

    });
})();

function returnData(){
    return sendData;
}
```

So there should not be any asynchronous issues in the script for accessing the URL because of .done. I really don't understand why this isn't working. I inspected my page and there are no errors to be seen anywhere. Can anyone help?

Comment: You never resolve the promise

Comment: If `access()` is asynchronous, then you will need to show us that code or explain how the caller would know when it's done.  Wrapping a promise around `access()` like you've done does not do anything useful.

Comment: Also, your `returnData()` function looks like a bad design as there is no way for any caller to know when the `sendData` value is actually available or not.

Comment: @jfriend00 i thought that the .done function would make it okay to send the data to a global variable. Is that bad practice?

Comment: Yeah, it's a bad practice.  Nobody outside the `.done()` function knows when `returnData()` actually has data to return.  And, there's no error handling on your `$.getJSON()` or any plan for how to communicate or deal with errors.

Answer (score 1):

`promise1` never gets resolved.

In your definition of `promise1`, you never call the `resolve()` function to resolve it.  Thus, it's `.then()` never gets called.

Manually created promises are only resolved when you explicitly call `resolve()` in the executor function.

If `access()` is itself asynchronous, then we will need to more about that function to help you do  this  correct.  Wrapping a promise around it does not do anything to help you.  If `access()` itself returns a promise, you should just use that promise and not wrap one around it.

---

Probably `access()` should return a promise that is resolved when it's asynchronous operation is done and then you can do:

```
access().then(...).catch(...);
```

And, not wrap it with another promise.

The `sendData` and `returnData()` stuff just looks wrong.  You'd have to explain and show more context to know what exactly the recommend.

Comment: access.js is the lastmost code that I posted, sorry. You're right I am wrapping a promise around the wrong thing and access.js isn't returning a promise. So I should be configuring method access.js itself to be a promise?

Comment: @h7651 - I don't know what `access()` is.  If you showed the code, we could make a recommendation.  But, if it's the asynchronous operation here, then it should be the one returning a promise and you can just use `.then()` on it without wrapping it in another promise.